# how to make my url work for all my buttons in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like that when I click on one of the 3 buttons it displays in the console, the country of buttons! I created this code there but the country is not defined, I don't know how to do it

For example :
I would like that when I click on the `<Button>France</Button>` in the console:
an object where there are the values ​​of state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Button from './components/Button';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      capital: "",
      flag: "",
      population: 0,
      region: "",

    }
  }

  componentDidMount(country) {
    const url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${country}`;
    
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json =>
        this.setState({
          name: json[0].name,
          capital: json[0].capital,
          flag: json[0].flag,
          population: json[0].population,
          region: json[0].region,
        }))
      .catch(error => error);

    console.log(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <p> name= {this.state.name}</p>
        <p> capital= {this.state.capital}</p>
        <p> flag= {this.state.flag}</p>
        <p> population= {this.state.population}</p>
        <p> region= {this.state.region}</p>

        <Button onClick={this.componentDidMount.bind(this, 'france')}>France</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.componentDidMount.bind(this, 'brazil')}>Brazil</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.componentDidMount.bind(this, 'croatia')}>Croatia</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

the `componentDidMount` is a function of the lifecycle of your component. It is called only when your component is rendered for the first time correctly. You can't call this function in the render function. You need to create a function and call it in the render method.

```
class App extends React.Component {

   handleClick = (country) => {
     // do what you want.
     console.log(country)
   }

   render() {
      <button onClick={() => handleClick('france')} />
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :), I tested and it worked, it generates a link, but now I have another little problem. How to get the url variable to put it in the fetch ()?
Because I tried to put this.url, this.handleClick ect ... and nothing works because in the end I want to display the name, capital ect .. in the console as an object!
thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

How to make my URL work for all my buttons in Reactjs?